# Online tool for testing voting systems?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Let's say that I have twenty candidates in a political race and that I want to run tests on the success of each candidate based on a variety of [voting systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system#Multiple-winner_methods). Is there a software that allowed me to do this, i.e. enter the candidates, pick voting system, run user tests, get results?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! You could try using Amazon's Mechanical Turk to collect data from users, but you will have to compute the results yourself. For most voting systems, you can probably do this in Excel fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it myself, but I think [PyVote](http://code.google.com/p/pyvote/) can do what you're interested in.  Might be overkill for your needs, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Although it looks like it's been dormant for a couple of years...

Comment: Yes, that software is basically vaporware now, and not ideal for this purpose.